# Angularfire2 FirebaseListObservable loading slowly on iOS

Tags: ios, angular, firebase, safari, angularfire2

I had an issue with an Angular2 app (that makes use of Angularfire2) where a FirebaseListObservable was loading considerably slower on mobile Safari compared to any other browser when deployed to production. The production domain was a custom one - not one provided by Firebase.

Running an iOS simulator using XCode, I could see the below error in the Safari web browsers's console.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to look at the firebase-auth info message, not the errors themselves.

To fix, I had to add my custom domain to the Firebase console to the list of 'OAuth redirect domains'. At the time of writing, this can be found here: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/[YOUR_PROJECT_ID_HERE]/authentication/providers